# Серверная часть android приложения

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

Разрабатываю приложение на `Android Cordova` (html,css,java script) впервые. Вся база хранится прямо в приложении (`json`).
До меня дошло, что json масивы немало весят и хорошо бы их загружать с сервера. Эм, "с сервера" - более ничего умного я не смог придумать. Посоветуйте какие-нибудь технологии и ключевые слова, куда мне рыть дабы реализовать загрузку с json массивов(или с бдшек) в андроид приложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется именно JavaScript решения, то Node.js конечно же! подключаешь к любой базе на выбор - например MongoDB, где запросы тоже можно делать с помощью JavaScript.

Наружу соответственно вываливаешь некий API, который тебе позволит принимать все эти данные в твое приложение.

Comment: спасибо за совет, но это нужно заводить хостинг - так ведь?

Comment: все так, либо можете использовать модные штуки вроде parse.com которые предоставляют "бекенд" к вашему мобильному приложению

Answer (score 0):

Можно и на самом устройстве разместить базу sqlite.

Comment: постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. Например, какой метод хранения json массивов использовать или вообще от них отказаться (как с javascript тогда стыковаться) -- даже если всё это кажется очевидным, стоит кратко упомянуть указания на препочтительные методы.